# Unwanted glue with boxes in Picture environment

Tags: asymptote, glue, picture-mode

Per request, here is the image of `mwe.pdf`:

[image: image of mwe.pdf]

See below for my problem, discussion of problem, and copy of `mwe.tex`.

---

This is a difficult query to present because it necessarily involves inserting an `aymptote` box into a picture environment.  Unfortunately, this is not an `asymptote` problem, so it must be presented in a LaTeX forum.

As discussed below, I (necessarily) use the `picture` environment to vertically align a `minipage` of free-form text with an `asymptote` diagram.  **Apparently(?)**, the `picture` environment **moderately** disrupts the horizontal positioning of the `asymptote` diagram with glue.

**How do I prevent the disruption of the `asymptote` diagram's horizontal positioning?**

### Discussion

A minimum working example of the problem is presented below. `asyboxa`, which draws the 4 quadrants of a circle, is hard-coded to create a 4cm by 4cm diagram. `boxa` presents a 6cm wide `minipage`, with its text aligned to the bottom of `boxa`.

The preamble sets the unitlength of 1cm, which controls how coordinates are interpreted in the `picture` environment. The first framed `picture` environment combines the `minipage` with the `asymptote` diagram while the second framed `picture` environment only presents the `asymptote` diagram.

In **both** frames, the manually drawn square indicates where the `asymptote` diagram is **intended** to be placed.  This can be confirmed by comparing the `\put` commands within each `picture` environment.  As the generated PDF will show, **both** `picture` environments are vertically positioning the `asymptote` diagrams as intended, but are also **(apparently) inserting unwanted glue that is disturbing the horizontal
positioning**.

Compile procedure:

1. Save the file as (for example) `mwe.tex`
2. Execute: `pdflatex mwe.tex`
3. Execute: `asy mwe-*.asy`
4. Execute: `pdflatex mwe.tex`

This should create `mwe.pdf`.  The `mwe.tex` file is shown below.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\newsavebox{\boxa}
\newsavebox{\asyboxa}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}

\begin{document}%

\begin{lrbox}{\asyboxa}%
\begin{asy}
size(4cm,4cm);
draw((-2,0) -- (2,0));
draw((0,-2) -- (0,2));
draw(circle((0,0), 2));
\end{asy}
\end{lrbox}%

\begin{lrbox}{\boxa}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{6cm}%
Minipage has 6cm width. \\%
Text alignment uses [b] option. \\%
Therefore last line of minipage \\%
is at bottom of boxa.
\end{minipage}%
\end{lrbox}%

\frame{%
\begin{picture}(11.5,4.5)
    \linethickness{.5mm}% 
    \put(0,0.2){\usebox\boxa}%
    \put(7.0,0.2){\usebox\asyboxa}%
        \put(7.0,0.2){\line(1,0){4.0}}%        
        \put(7.0,4.2){\line(1,0){4.0}}%
        \put(7.0,0.2){\line(0,1){4.0}}%
        \put(11.0,0.2){\line(0,1){4.0}}%
\end{picture}%
}%

\vspace*{36pt}%

\frame{%
\begin{picture}(5.5,4.5)
    \linethickness{.5mm}% 
    \put(1.0,0.2){\usebox\asyboxa}%
        \put(1.0,0.2){\line(1,0){4.0}}%        
        \put(1.0,4.2){\line(1,0){4.0}}%
        \put(1.0,0.2){\line(0,1){4.0}}%
        \put(5.0,0.2){\line(0,1){4.0}}%
\end{picture}%
}%

\end{document}
```

### Addendum

Two additions to the query.

1. I added the `asymptote` tag, since other `asymptote` users may have {struggled with -- solved} the problem.
2. I experimented by defining the `picture` environment wide enough to extend the right side margin, defining a (very wide) `savebox` to contain the `asymptote` box flush left, and having the `picture` environment `\put` the `savebox` instead of the `asymptote` box -- **No Joy**.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: you are defining a picture 5.5cm wide and 4.5cm high and place objects inside it. The stated bounding box is fully respected.

Comment: @egreg "The stated bounding box is fully respected." Yes, but within the bounding box, the picture environment is **not** placing the lower left hand corner of asyboxa at (1.0, 0.2), as it should.  This disruption is verified by the picture environment's placing of the 4 line segments.

Comment: If I put your second `picture` environment in a `\fbox` with `\fboxsep` set to zero, adding `\put(0,0){\circle*{0.1}}` and `\put(5.5,4.5){\circle*{0.1}}` just to mark the bounding box, I get [this picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DLw6.png). The Asymptote drawing sits exactly at (1,0.2).

Comment: @egreg First of all, **thank you** for your attention.  I have two reactions, depending on what you are implying.  Either (1) **Wow**, you have solved it. or (2) You have **misinterpreted** my intent.  **Please** post your *solution* as an answer, **including the latex code, so that I can create my own pdf.  see next comment

Comment: @ egreg <continuation of earlier comment>.  **However,** the point of this query **is not** to reproduce a quartered circle in the picture environment, but to do **all of the drawing** in asymptote (et al, e.g. pstricks, tikz, ...) and use the picture environment to precisely control the placement of the diagram.  Therefore, I am looking for a solution (perhaps using **fbox**) that **employs asyboxa**

Comment: Why aren't you posting a picture for comparison?

Comment: @egreg "Why aren't you posting...?"  Good point; I didn't realize how easy it is.  I have updated the original query with an image of the resultant mwe.pdf.

Comment: OK, that's a known problem. On the other hand, newer TeX distributions should have a fixed `asymptote.sty`.

Comment: @egreg Please see the *answer* that I just posted.  Thanks for your insight.